# ARR/IIS 502 Errors When Returning JSON

Tags: web-services, iis, asp.net-web-api, url-rewriting, arr

Here's our current setup: (assume everything is using https)

- Web Services server running a simple asp.NET Web API 2 application that returns only JSON. (api.example.com/controller/blah)
- Primary web server that's going to contain scripts that use AJAX to access resources through our Web Services.

My end goal is to not have to deal with CORS because IE is being problematic. (I've tried several jQuery plugins to resolve problems with XDomainRequest, on top of our domain security settings causing IE to deny the requests anyways... it's just a mess.)

- Route requests from www.example.com/api/* to api.example.com/* and return the JSON response.

However, when I've attempted to set this up with IIS + URL Rewrite + Application Request Routing (ARR) I get the following message when attempting to load up my url:

> **502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.**
>
> There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be
>   displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy)
>   contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response
>   from the content server.

My setup in IIS is the following:

> - In ARR, I just ticked the **Enable proxy** option.
> - In URL Rewrite, I set up a rule with:
> - - Match PRL Pattern = **api/*** (Using wildcards)
> - - Action type = **Rewrite**
> - - Rewrite URL: = **api.example.com/{R:1}**

I've made sure I can access the web services and data is returned correctly from the context of my web server. I've made sure the actual URL Rewrite rule is being triggered and forwarding the request correctly... but after that, I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: hdid you ever resolve this as I am having the same problem, I am returning a big json and this is not working? I increased the maxLength option in my web.config also.